# How to get dd MMM yyyy format? (Month name in capital)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need a specific datetime formatting which is `dd MMM yyyy (01 JAN 2021)`.
I did extract the date from excel and I get the usual `yyyy-mm-dd (2021-01-01)`. I converted the date by using `df.dt.strftime('%d %b %Y')` which gave me `01 Jan 2021`. The problem is that the month is written as 'Jan' and not 'JAN'.

Could anyone shed a light for me?

Comment: Convert it to capital i.e. upper using after formatting the time, i.e. `df[col].dt.strftime('%d %b %Y').str.upper()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `upper()`:

```
print(df.dt.strftime("%Y-%B-%d").upper())
```

Comment: works as a charm! thank you so much for helping a newbie

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {0: '2021-01-01', 1: '2021-02-01', 2: '2021-03-01'}})

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%d %b %Y').str.upper()

df['time']
```

output:

```
0    01 JAN 2021
1    01 FEB 2021
2    01 MAR 2021
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help!! i really appreciate it